# Почему смартфон не ограничивает fps?

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview

Я не могу разобраться с таким вопросом. Написал тестовую программу (по книге) для вывода графики на экран. При этом программа высчитывает время между кадрами, вычисляет их частоту в секунду (fps) и выводит в консоль. В результате я вижу, что fps варьируется от 30 до 75. В тоже время где-то читал, что смартфоны (кроме новых моделей) ограничивают fps <= 60.  Я решил, что может быть это погрешности при вычислении fps. Но когда дошёл до следующей главы и начал выводить графику с помощью openGL fps стал больше 1000!!! Тут на погрешность вычисления не спишешь. Подскажите, почему так происходит? Почему такой высокий fps, если он должен быть ограничен смартфоном? Что я неправильно понял при изучении скорости вывода на экран?

Вот код с помощью которого я вычисляю fps:

```
    long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    update();//обновление объектов
    draw();// вывод объектов на экран
    long timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
    fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
```

Comment: 1000 fps на Андроиде?! - хорошая шутка, но 1 апреля уже прошло. Скорее всего вы неправильно считаете, я сомневаюсь что любой аппарат сможет лог печатать с такой скоростью, не то что кадр выводить.

Comment: @woesss, я не собирался шутить. Вычисляю fps стандартным способом. Запоминаю время начала цикла, потом запоминаю время окончания цикла. Нахожу разность. fps = 1000/разность. В общем делаю так как автор книги советует. Сам автор пишет, что у него fps = 200, а также пишет, что тестировщики книги указывали, что на некоторых устройствах fps = 1000 и больше! И он говорит, что на таких устройствах нужно предусмотреть ограничитель частоты, чтобы зря аккумулятор не разряжать. Вот книга: John Horton "Android Game Programming by Example" 2015

Comment: И что вы предлагаете всем купить книгу, чтобы посмотреть код, который вы оттуда взяли, при чём неизвестно как вы его применили? Показывайте ваш код - посмотрим что вы там считаете.

Comment: @woesss, в вопрос я добавил свой код. Он ничем не отличается от того, что я описал в предыдущем комментарии

Comment: @woesss сейчас компьютеры средней дохлости способны выдать около 3000-20000 fps (прямо сейчас у меня glxgears в 720p выдаёт 4000 fps). Я не вижу никаких технических причин, чтобы даже более дохлый андроид не мог бы выдывать эти самые 1000 fps, особенно если вдруг речь не о FullHD

Comment: Я бы советовал считать по другому алгоритму. Считать кол-во циклов обновления и суммировать время на обновление. Как только время перешагнёт за 1 секунду, выводить фпс, сбрасывать счётчик, вычитать из времени 1сек. Так фпс не будет скакать как бешеный

Comment: @ArchDemon, у меня нет претензий к скорости вывода fps, я не могу понять почему смартфон выдаёт 1000 fps, если вроде бы должен ограничивать частоту fps <= 60

Comment: А может быть `Draw()` реально выводит не каждый раз? Скажем, если от предыдущего вызова прошло меньше 1/60 sec, то реально вывод на экран не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку не указано иное, предполагаю что весь этот код вписан в метод
`onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` реализации `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. Тогда он считает теоретическую производительность двух вызываемых методов и эта цифра не имеет ничего общего с реальным выводом кадров на экран.
`draw();// вывод объектов на экран` - комментарий здесь наглая ложь, объекты в принципе не выводятся на экран, а рендерятся в фрейм-буфер, который уже может выводиться, но опять же не здесь. Вывод на экран вызывается после завершения метода `onDrawFrame()` в классе `GLSurfaceView`, счётчик не учитывает ни это время, ни время между вызовами, а также тот факт, что вызовы большинства функций GL не блокирующие (то есть вызов вернулся в ваш код, а рендеринг ещё не завершён)
Более близким к правде будет такой подсчёт:

```
private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
private int frameCount = 0;

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    update();//обновление объектов
    draw();// рендеринг объектов
    frameCount++;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((currentTime - startTime) >= 1000) {
        fps = frameCount;
        frameCount = 0;
        startTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Здесь мы тоже бежим вперёд паровоза - считаем кадр завершённым ещё до вывода на экран, но учитываем всё время между двумя вызовами `onDrawFrame`, поэтому можем смело считать что получаем средний показатель количества кадров в секунду.

P.S. автору вопроса рекомендую почитать справку [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), чтобы мы не догадывались, не вытаскивали информацию клещами и максимально быстро получать ответы)

Comment: при использовании вашего способа вычисления получаю fps почти =60. Это явно более точный метод. Не знаю, почему автор книги этого не учёл